# call javascript function with parameters from php code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want call a javascript function from php and execute a ajax call.My php code is:

```
echo '<script>change2('.$stand.'); </script>';
```

and my js code is :

```
function change2(c){
alert(c);
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","change2.php?c="+c,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    }
```

The alert return undifined..

Comment: If c is a string put it like '<script>change2("'.$stand.'"); </script>';

Comment: Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert your php object to a correctly encode js _value_ (`'<script>change2('.json_encode($stand).');</script>'`)

Comment: You shouldn't use IE6 or IE5 hacks anymore. There is no need to - see http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp. To answer your question, i think Limiter is right, you have to wrap the $stand between "

Comment: $stand is a number,not string..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this : `<input type="hidden" value="<?php $stand ?>" id="someID">`
and in your Js

```
<script>change2(document.getElementByID('someID'); </script>
```

I think it's working.

Comment: I might be wrong but `<?php $stand ?>`  without an `echo` would not work. Anyway even if it would, you need to properly escape the values so that it will work even it `$stand` contains a `"`.